# Jquery focusout function

Tags: jquery, jquery-focusout

Is possible to pass the element to the focusout function in Jquery? I would like to tie all textboxes focusout event in one statement. So my solution would be to make them all the same class and then do something like

```
$(".class-name").focusout( function() {
//do whatever
});
```

But I would like to get the value of the element inside the focusout without having to refer to it by its id, so is something like this possible?

```
$(".class-name").focusout( function(this) {
alert( $(this).val() );
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<del>Assuming you realize the magical nature of `focusout` over `blur`,</del> this is what you want:

```
$("#the-common-parent-of-all-inputs").focusout( function(e) {
alert( e.target.value );
});
```

You only need to bind one `focusout` to the common parent of the input elements.This is the only reason to use `focusout`.

You may not realize it but when you do `$(".class-name").focusout` it will just bind to each element individually, which defeats the whole purpose of `focusout`.

Comment: I read this on jquery.com. "This is distinct from the blur event in that it supports detecting the loss of focus from parent elements (in other words, it supports event bubbling)." I am not quite sure what parent element is. looking this up now

Comment: @sarsnake, it's like this:
`<form><input><input><input></form>`. Now you only bind single focusout to the FORM, because its the common parent for all inputs. Instead of 3 blur events, one for each input. The specific input that triggered the blur is available through `e.target`. `this` will always refer to the form because it's what the event was bound on.

Answer (score 5):

For something like focusout (or any other jQuery event) you can do:

```
$(".class-name").focusout( function() {
   //`this` refers to the object that was focusouted on
});
```

`this` always refers to the object the event happened on

Comment: `this` would refer to whatever `.class-name` parent catched the bubbled event, not to the lower level element that the blur event originally happened on. It is only in the case where `.class-name` was the element itself that the blur event happened on.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try it? It should definitely work, but without(!) the "this" parameter. "this" will automatically refer to the current element, no need to pass it to the function as a parameter. Just omit it.